# using Service in android application

Tags: android, android-service

this code is work with me to take the coordination even if the application is not in use but when i switch of my phone then open my phone again it is not working in the background i need it continue working in the background. even if the user mobile pone is switched off and then it is opened again

```
    public class Check2 extends  Service
{

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    }

    private static final String TAG = "GPS";
        private LocationManager mLocationManager = null;
        private static final int LOCATION_INTERVAL = 1000*6;
        private static final float LOCATION_DISTANCE = 0f;

        private class LocationListener implements android.location.LocationListener{
            Location mLastLocation;

            public LocationListener(String provider)
            {

                Log.e(TAG, "LocationListener " + provider);
                mLastLocation = new Location(provider);

            }

            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
            {
                Log.e(TAG, "onLocationChanged: " + location);
                mLastLocation.set(location);


                double lat = mLastLocation.getLatitude();;
                double lon =  mLastLocation.getLongitude();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Lat: "+lat+" Long: "+lon, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
            {
                Log.e(TAG, "onProviderDisabled: " + provider);
            }
            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
            {
                Log.e(TAG, "onProviderEnabled: " + provider);
            }
            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
            {
                Log.e(TAG, "onStatusChanged: " + provider);
            }
        }
        LocationListener[] mLocationListeners = new LocationListener[] {
                new LocationListener(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER),
                new LocationListener(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
        };
        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
        {
            return null;
        }


        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
        {
            LocationManager loc;
            loc=(LocationManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            LocationListener listener =new LocationListener(TAG);
            Location location ;
            Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand");
            super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
            initializeLocationManager();
            try {

                mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                        mLocationListeners[1]);


                 //   location = listener.mLastLocation;
                location= loc.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                    listener.onLocationChanged(location);

                Log.d("is work","here");
            } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
                Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
                Log.d(TAG, "network provider does not exist, " + ex.getMessage());
            }
            try {

                mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                        mLocationListeners[0]);
                location= loc.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                listener.onLocationChanged(location);

                Log.d("is work", "here");
            } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
                Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
                Log.d(TAG, "gps provider does not exist " + ex.getMessage());
            }
            return START_STICKY;
        }


    @Override
        public void onCreate()
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");

        }
        @Override
        public void onDestroy()
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy");
            super.onDestroy();
            if (mLocationManager != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < mLocationListeners.length; i++) {
                    try {
                        mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListeners[i]);
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "fail to remove location listners, ignore", ex);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    private void initializeLocationManager() {
        Log.e(TAG, "initializeLocationManager");
        if (mLocationManager == null) {
            mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Broadcast receiver to listen for Boot Complete event

Check this link for tutorials
[Broadcast receiver for Boot Action](http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/07/bootcompleted-broadcastreceiver-in.html)

Comment: do you mean put this code in broadcast or put intent to broadcast

Comment: in broadcast receiver **onReceive method** call your service class

Answer (score 0):

- 1 to Vivek, but also you should start your service in another process from your application. For example,

  << service
            android:name=".TweetCollectorService"

  ```
        android:process=":remote">
  ```

Then in your service you should add BroadcastReceiver to receive intent BOOT_COMPLETE. If you want this service to keep running no matter what, consider replacind `startService` method with `startForeground`